# How to load certificates from window's key store in php?

Tags: php, certificate

I am currently working on an PHP application which will be used as customer on-boarding web app, some **sensitive information** like Bank Detail and others will also send through some form submission. Now requirement is, at time of submitting data(form) customer should encrypt and digitally signed that form's data with the digital certificate stored at **Windows Key Store** under user's account. After two days of research i can't figure out the way that how to access user's windows key store through website?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Do you mean window credential manager?

Comment: @shingo windows key store where widows stores digital certificate.